# Waypoints JavaScript(Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am developing a webpage and  I wanted to know how to go about making animations based on where the page currently is.

What I mean is that : 
for example, the Markup below

```
<body>
    <div id = "header">
        <p> header content goes here</p>
    </div>


    <div id = "content">

        <div id = "first">
            <p>when I sroll into this region I want the background to darken up(and information appears) and an arrow to appear at the bottom showing prompting to scroll down</p>
        </div>

        <div id = "second">
            <p>when I sroll into this region I want the navbar to to change appearace and display info relative to that div only </p>
        </div>

        <div id = "third">
            <p>when I scroll into this region I want a another effect to occur</p>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div id = "footer">
        <p>footer content goes here</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

if the web page loads and I scroll into each of the three divs in the  then i want to have a defined effect in action.
How do I do I go about that in JavaScript(Jquery)? or if anyone knows of any good sources where i can learn this technique i will love to know

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently. I found the free and open-source divPeek library to be excellent.

https://github.com/davidhalford/DivPeek

No need to reinvent the wheel, especially if it has already been invented! :)

Comment: @rydan thanks for accepting. If it helped, would you mind pushing the up arrow next to my answer as well? It won't hurt, promise!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick, either inside the `pageLoad` or `$(document).ready` methods:

```
var last, 
  docHeight= $(window).height(),
  firstTop = $("#first").offset().top,
  firstBottom = firstTop - docHeight,
  secondTop = $("#second").offset().top,
  secondBottom = secondTop - docHeight,
  thirdTop = $("#third").offset().top,
  thirdBottom = thirdTop - docHeight;



$(document).scroll(function(){
  var thisTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  if(thisTop <= thirdTop && thisTop >= thirdBottom){//#third is now visible
    if(last != 3)//check if we're already in #third
        console.log("entered third");//we entered #third for the first time, trigger effect
    last = 3;
  } else if (thisTop <= secondTop && thisTop >= secondBottom){
    if(last != 2)
        console.log("entered second");
    last = 2;
  } else if (thisTop <= firstTop && thisTop >= firstBottom){
    if(last != 1)
        console.log("entered first");
    last = 1
  } else 
    last = 0;
})
```

It attaches to the `$(document).scroll` event, and using jquery's `scrollTop()` for the document, and `offset().top` of the elements, determines which one has been scrolled to.  It also keeps a variable with the last element that was scrolled to, so the `console.log` statements are only fired when the element is scrolled to originally, thus it won't fire while scrolling through the element.

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymMS6/)